Questions regarding Non-precision Localiser approach (KSEE LOC-D Approach)
Scenario
Say we are doing some practice approaches into KSEE on the LOC-D approach. We are just southwest of the field and ATC/CFII says to climb to 5500 direct to BARET, cross BARET 5500 cleared for the localizer approach. So we climb to 5500 direct to BARET. We fly direct to BARET on Magenta needles. Once we get over BARET (Established outbound) we switch from Magenta to green needles for the loc-d approach and we fly our procedure turn to 134 heading for 1 minute outbound. Once the minute is up, we turn left heading of 314 to intercept the localiser course.
My questions
#1 This would put us between WOPOS and BARET under the IAP published altitudes (WOPOS is 6800 and BARET is 5900), since we have been at 5500 since crossing BARET. Would we just maintain this altitude until crossing BARET for ZIRLU which is 4900. Does the updated 'clearance' of 5500 trump over the published altitudes?
#2 can we use GPS (magenta needles) to fly the published missed to the VOR?


You should never get this clearance, and should reject it if you did. The procedure turn takes you close to peaks that are nearly 5000 feet. 5500 feet is a clearly inadequate altitude.
You can fly the missed approach with an approved GPS.

Even if it was a practice clearance for a practice approach from a DPE/CFII? My DPE gave me this while VFR during my checkride acting as ATC for my ride. Ok, thanks for clarifying the missed with GPS!

@TrevorMiller I'm not sure it's helpful to ask students to fly practice approaches in ways they never would in real life! And even VFR with a CFII watching that's pretty darn low over mountainous terrain! On a cold day you might actually hit a mountain!

Hey Chris, I updated my comment on the situation! I agree 100% with you, this just happened to me and I was confused. I believe I was left so low because of the Bravo from 5800 to 10000

@TrevorMiller Seems likely. I'd not worry about it too much. If it was your CFII I'd suggest you have a talk with them about briefing things more carefully when they are deviations from realistic IFR flight. Congratulations (I hope) on your instrument rating!

Roger that and thank you!! I appreciate the insight

one quick question! The lod/dme freq 110.5 has an underline to it. Does that mean it doesn't have morse code to identify it?

@TrevorMiller Not quite. It means there is no voice on the frequency. Some navaids you can do voice communications over the frequency.

So if I was flying to KSEE about to fly this approach (LOC-D) and I had the frequency on and I check it with the nav function, it should or shouldn't have a morse code? Trying to understand what No voice means for the approach! Thanks for the quick response as well

@TrevorMiller It should have a morse code. No voice means as it sounds- nobody can verbally talk to you on the frequency.

Roger that thanks Chris!
